# Mortar combing direction in relation to tile ridges

Tags: tile

A section of the tiles on the terrace at my grandma's house in Thailand (i.e. very tropical climate) is tenting after more than 40 years. I'm trying to put it back down.

1. The old diamond-shaped tiles have directional ridges underneath as opposed to the usual grid, as you can see from the imprints left on the mortar.  In which direction should comb the mortar in light of this, if it matters at all?  Since the original setter apparently didn't care about arranging the tiles so that their ridges run in the same direction, I'm guessing that he combed the mortar in the direction of the diamond's axis of symmetry (and perpendicular to the façade), which will be at a 45-degree angle to the ridges no matter what.   Perhaps I should do that since it's held up for 40 years, but since, unlike him, I will be combing with some old tiles in place, I would much rather be doing so parallel or perpendicular to the tiles' edges, and that would mean either combing along ridges or against the ridges. Which is better in your opinion?

[image: tiles]

2. What kind of trowel should I use? The tiles are about 3" x 3" (edge x edge, 7.5 cm x 7.5 cm) and ridges are less than 1/16" tall (about 1 mm, maybe).
3. How much of the old mortar do I have to remove from the concrete substrate and underside of the tiles? And how should I go about it?
4. Do I need to install a new uncoupling membrane? I see traces of the old one (I think) that looks like a simple net. I'm afraid that a heavy-duty modern membrane will add too much to the thickness of the repaired section and make it taller than the rest.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The TCNA Handbook calls for movement joints every 8 ft to 12 ft for outdoor tile installations. The intention is to allow thermal expansion, where I suspect that your tenting has resulted from such expansion.

Typically thinset specifies a maximum thickness. You can apply multiple layers of the thinset with substantial curing between applications as long as the total thickness is less than the specified maximum thickness. Without knowing the specified maximum thickness for the existing thinset, then, it's hard to say whether it's safe to apply new thinset over the top and re-lay the tile. I'd be tempted to use a product like Mapei's ECO-Prim Grip and install the new thinset plus tiles over that, but I unfortunately don't understand the mechanics involved.

Constrained by the elevation of adjacent tile, you should chip the old thinset off the concrete substrate. The professional way is with a [pulverizing bit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BZYW9TPW) for a rotary hammer running in hammer mode:

[image: pulverizing bit]

As for thinset stuck to tiles, leave it alone. There's a good chance of breaking such tiles as you try to clean them up, and it doesn't sound like you have spares. Install these tiles at the middle of patches where you can cheat a thin layer of thinset between the concrete and the tile. Use the pulverizing bit to chip the concrete substrate down to its aggregate to make some more room for fresh thinset under these tiles. A little bit of a bulge is preferable to broken tiles, but hopefully this is a false choice and you can avoid both.

For square tile the thinset combing direction doesn't matter. The thinset ridges are intended to allow air to escape from under the tiles, so for out-of-square tiles it's technically better to comb the thinset to minimize the distance that air must travel to escape. For square tile that distance is the same regardless of combing direction, so there's no need to worry about it.

My speculation is that the tile ridges are intended to provide extra surface area for thinset bonding. Additionally they could provide some "mechanical interlock" like the lugs on rebar. Assuming that the netting in the thinset was originally glued to the tile by the manufacturer as an installation aid and further noting the chaotic orientation of tile ridge imprints in the old thinset, I reason that the "mechanical interlock" direction doesn't matter. But the bond for these tiles has failed, so replicating their installation pattern could be flawed reasoning. Sometimes tiles break free of the manufacturer's netting (when the glue between the tile and netting gets wet), where that would give the prior installer the freedom to rearrange the tile ridge orientation in defiance of the manufacturer's intention. You might alternate the tile ridge direction just to be safe.

I suppose that running the tile ridges parallel to the thinset combing ridges could better allow any air to escape. I'm not concerned, but back buttering the tiles would eliminate the hypothetical problem.

For 3 inch tile, a 1/4 inch v-notch trowel is appropriate. To minimize out of levelness with adjacent tile, I would experiment with a few different trowels. A 3/16 inch v-notch trowel is the absolute minimum and it may be too small.

The embedded net in the thinset was probably glued to the tiles by the manufacturer to facilitate installation. It's not an uncoupling membrane. An uncoupling membrane sounds infeasible unless you're redoing the whole installation. I suppose you could also use an uncoupling membrane if you pulled up additional tile to make large rectangular patches, but hopefully the undisturbed tiles are so well bonded that they would thwart the attempt.

Comment: Thank you for your expert answer. I understand that "thinset ridges are intended to allow air to escape from under the tiles", but what are the tile's *own* ridges for, and how do they interact with the the thinset ridges? Given that we're putting ridges against ridges, it seems to me the angle they make with one another should matter, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Bongbang, my speculation is that these ridges are intended to increase the surface area in contact with thinset. Such ridges also provide some mechanical interlock with the thinset in addition to the thinset's adhesion. The combed direction of the thinset doesn't impact either of these guesses. Alternating the direction of the tile ridges would provide equivalent mechanical interlock strengths in two perpendicular directions, so that could be worthwhile. This is all just speculation, however.

Comment: @Bongbang, and the combed ridges in the thinset are collapsed by proper tile installation. In the end, then, the combed direction of the thinset vanishes making it irrelevant to the tile installation. I suppose the air might escape better if the ridges align with the thinset, but I'm skeptical. If it concerns you, then consider back buttering the tiles instead of obsessing over the thinset combed direction. I wouldn't worry about it, and I would never back butter 3" tile unless it was natural stone tile.

Comment: @bongbang - The direction of troweled thinset is irrelevant in a proper tile installation. The only thing that changes is which way you slide it back and forth an eighth of an inch, to set the tile (so that it *doesn't* look like your pic and therefore never fails). - I'd rather fudge a **backbutter** (prob by eventually giving up and using the flat side) than tear up the old thinset. If you do that then it just becomes a normal tile job. And you might as well pop the rest up and start over, because as usual, they can't be all that far from failing too.

Comment: @Mazura, my understanding is that those aren't uncollapsed ridges imprinted in the thinset. They mirror ridges on the backs of the tiles. Note how the ridges stop short of the tile edges by a very regular offset with no exceptions. Resetting the tiles with epoxy might allow reinstallation with less of a bust in the floor's flatness. Sounds like it never gets any freeze/thaw.

Comment: Thinset is typically pretty weak I wouldn't use that pulverizing bit - I'd just use a turbo concrete grinder but start with just a wide chisel bit to remove the majority of the old thinset.